# Contradictory arguments for ATM/ITM/OTM option demand

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, european-options, volatility-smile

I am trying to understand which of the options have the most demand, and found this discussion [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33982/why-is-there-greater-demand-for-otm-and-itm-options-than-for-atm-options). The arguments presented are as follows:

1. ATM is more liquidly traded than ITM/OTM because they are easiest to obtain gamma/vega exposure at lowest bid-ask spreads.
2. ITM/OTM are more liquidly traded than ATM because OMMs typically look at volatility (instead of underlying) characteristics and ITM/OTM have less vol-sensitivity than ATM.

Both are incredibly convincing but contradictory, could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: The answer may depend on which underlying you are talking about

Comment: In the title, I think you mean “option liquidity” and not “option demand”. Demand is not an observable quantity but a function of price.